# Export custom column in Ag Grid to excel

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I have a custom column in Ag Grid which has an image and text in it.
When I export the whole table to excel I get [object] as value for the custom column.

Is there a way to export only the text from the custom column?

Project is in Angular typescript

Answer (score 1):

Good day, [please have a look at the docs of customising-cell-and-row-group-values](https://ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/excel-export-customising-content/#customising-cell-and-row-group-values)

**Description:**

You can create custom options and describe what exact field should be passed in export with concrete value:

1. [First look for how can create custom options](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/context-menu/#configuring-the-context-menu)
2. [Looking for exportDataAsExcel method and ExcelExportParams](https://ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/excel-export-api/#excelexportparams)

**Example:**

```
const getContextMenuItems = ({ api, ...restProps }) => {
  return [
    // other options
    {
      name: 'Export',
      tooltip: 'Export',
      subMenu: [
        {
          name: 'Excel Export',
          action: () => api.exportDataAsExcel({
             // other params like columnKeys e.t.c
             processCellCallback: ({ column, value }) => {
                // Rules for your custom cellRenderer here:
                if (column.colId === 'yourCustomFieldId') {
                    return value.customText;
                }

                return value;
             },
         }),
        },
      ],
    },
  ];
};
```